# How to get an image to fade in when the mouse is hovered over?

Tags: css, filter, onhover

I received this tip:

```
.container img{
     width:125px;
     margin;0;
     padding:0;
     opacity:0.5;
}
.container img:hover{
   opacity:1;
}
```

Tried it and it worked great!

I then used a light version of a Custom CSS Editor Plugin - popped the code into it and added the class container `<p class="container">` to the images and it worked.

Comment: Look into using a `transition`

Comment: your question does not include a detailed description of your problem, any previous attempts, any existing code or further information, as well as not many words. it *does* contain a link, though - this could be borderline to spam.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort - **apologies** for lack of information.  I will better details when I next post.  In the meantime Anuja Agarwal has provided me with information to work with - so than you.  Cliff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use opacity property for the image:

```css
.container img{
  width:300px;
  margin;0;
  padding:0;
  opacity:0.5;
}
.container img:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.booths.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/640px-X-360px-Chocolate-MiniNests.jpg"/>
</div>
```